# Trigger.io native module - Method not supported on this platform

Tags: trigger.io

I have developed a custom native module to keep the screen awake while in my application.

After testing the module with forgeInspector, and adding it to my application via the trigger.io toolkit, this error shows in the console log:

```
[DEBUG] Returned: {"content":{"message":"Method not supported on this platform","type":"UNAVAILABLE","subtype":null},"callid":"CE53E970-807C-4179-8F02-BCAF4950A0AB","status":"error"}
```

Using JavaScript, I am calling the module by the following:

```
forge.stayawake.showAlert('test alert box',function(){alert('success');},function(e){ alert(e); });
```

My module.js is:

```
forge.stayawake = {
    showAlert: function (text, success, error) {
        forge.internal.call('stayawake.showAlert', {text: text}, success, error);
    }
};
```

io.trigger.forge.android.modules.stayawake reads

```
package io.trigger.forge.android.modules.stayawake;

import io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeApp;
import io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeParam;
import io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeTask;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class API {
    public static void showAlert(final ForgeTask task, @ForgeParam("text") final String text) {
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            // Error if there is no text to show
            task.error("No text entered");
            return;
        }
        task.performUI(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ForgeApp.getActivity());
                builder.setMessage(text).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        task.success();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As a control test, to make sure the module is actually loading properly I tried renaming the "stayawake.set" to "foo.test" and I get the exact same message.

I have also reverted everything back to the initial download of inspector. If I include that in my main application and call the default "showAlert" I get still get the error `Method not supported on this platform`. Again, everything works fine when testing with inspector.

I have followed all of the instructions found at trigger.io and still no go.

Am I just not calling my module the correct or way?

Comment: So, to continue testing I reverted everything back to the initial download of inspector. If I include that in my main application and call the default "showAlert" I get the error "Method not supported on this platform". Again, everything works fine when testing with inspector.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

After receiving the same error in the same situation, I realised that I'd missed the Android building step of the module:

https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/the_basics.html

> **Building/packaging your module**
>
> **Android**
>
> To build and export your module
>   to be included in an actual Forge app:
>
> - Right click the `src` folder and choose Export...
> - Use the wizard to export the contents of the folder as a JAR
> - You must include the generated class files and resource in the JAR (Java source is not required)
> - Save that jar as `android/module.jar` in your module folder. (`module_name/module/android/module.jar`)

Here's a screenshot of my settings:

[image: Settings]

I was then able to upload the module and include it in my project successfully, without the error above.